# C# How to display Dataset's Byte column as an Enum in MS Reporting Services?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, enums, dataset

How to **display an Enumeration Value** in Microsoft reporting based on the byte column from a DataTable?

I want to cast

```
=Fields!Status.Value
```

to something like `(MyEnum)Fields!Status.Value`

and then call `.ToString()` on it.
Status is a Byte type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I made it this way (this is what I've inserted directly into the table cell):

```
=Switch(
Fields!status.Value=0, "NotStarted",
Fields!status.Value=1, "InProgress",
Fields!status.Value=2, "Completed",
Fields!status.Value=3, "Deferred"
)
```